# Lowest score that has never scored by a batsman in an innings?

Tags: cricket, records

What is the lowest score that has never been scored by a batsman in an innings?
For instance, there is no player who has ever scored an *82* in T20Is. Is there a further lower score that has never been scored?

It would be great if you could answer for Test, ODIs and T20s each.

Comment: What an interest question. I would imagine ODIs would be 150+ and Test is 200+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: this was correct as of Feb 2015, but subject to change. For the correct answer as of Jan 2017, and a quick way of finding the current scores, see answer by Moaz0786.

Test match: lowest score never achieved by batsman in an innings as of 2015 [is 229](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;orderby=batted_score;page=3;template=results;type=batting;view=innings).

[image: Cricinfo Test Scores 227-231]

One Day International: lowest score never achieved as of 2015 [is 155](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=2;filter=advanced;orderby=batted_score;page=2;template=results;type=batting;view=innings).

[image: Cricinfo ODI runs around 155]

T20 International: lowest score never achieved as of 2015 [is 82](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=3;filter=advanced;orderby=batted_score;page=2;template=results;type=batting;view=innings)

[image]

A note on the method: I kept scrolling on the links until I got the impression that there was no way a missing lower score could appear. This was at 200 for tests, at 119 for ODI and at 50 for T20I. For instance in ODIs, 119 has been scored 31 times, and 3 times by Viv Richards alone, so I am pretty confident that all lower values will have been scored, but I didn't do an exhaustive check all the way down to 0.

Comment: I had the same doubt too actually. Perhaps the score 61 was never scored in T20s or something although such an occurrence is highly improbable. I'm going with this as accepted, unless it's disproved.

Answer (score 7):

For Tests and ODIs, Fillet's answer is correct: The lowest score that has never been scored in a Test innings remains **229**, which is also the lowest score never achieved in any international, and the lowest score that has never been scored in ODIs remains **155**. However, there were three innings of 82* in Twenty20 Internationals in 2016:
[image: Screenshot showing three scores of 82* in 2016 T20Is]
The current lowest score that has never been achieved in a Twenty20 International is **92**:
[image: Screenshot showing three scores of between 91 and 93, but none of 92, in T20Is]
The method used to find these scores was the following Bash command:

```
for i in {0..400};do if [ "`wget -O- -q "http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;orderby=batted_score;runsmin1=${i};runsmax1=${i};runsval1=runs;size=10;template=results;type=batting;view=innings" | grep "player.*data-link" | grep -o '[>][^<>]\+[<]' | tr -d '<>' | wc -l`" -eq 0 ]; then echo "${i}";break;fi;done
```

`class=1` is for Test matches; this can be changed to `class=2` for ODIs, `class=3` for Twenty20 Internationals, and `class=11` for all internationals.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answers above:

First class: **326**

[List A](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/117935.html): **193**

[T20](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/284198.html): **132**

Comment: 92 is the lowest T20I score not scored. Your link does not provide evidence for a score of 92, or all scores from 93 to 131, having already been scored.

Comment: @Nij You're right 92 is the highest not scored in T20 _internationals_ . But 92 has been scored 30 times in T20 cricket (domestic matches).  Here's an example: [Gayle for RCB](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8082/scorecard/521347/Royal-Challengers-Bangalore-vs-New-South-Wales-1st-Semi-Final-Nokia-Champions-League-T20-2011-12/)

Answer (score 1):

I understand this thread was posted 5 years prior to my comment today; 
However here's an update for the stat fueled nerds amongst you; as of March 2020 both the lowest Test and ODI scores still stand at: 229 and 155 respectively.

Since 2017 the former record of 92 has been achieved in T20I matches 4 times,
the new lowest remaining score is 108! (Followed by 112)

[image]

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers. It is at best a comment pointing out they are still accurate, which should be done by editing to acknowledge the latest time of correct information.